# Сбросить слушателя с кнопки RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava, onclicklistener

Пробую первый день писать с использованием RxJava. Весь день не могу понять, как удалить слушатель с кнопки. ClickEvent у меня это просто object пустой, хочу научиться ловить клик.

```
val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

val observable: Observable<ClickEvent> = Observable.create<ClickEvent> { emitter ->

    val listener = View.OnClickListener {
        object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                emitter.onNext(ClickEvent)
            }
        }
    }
   button.setOnClickListener(listener)
   emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromAction {
      button. // сбросить слушатель
   })

}
```

Comment: setOnClickListener(null)?

Comment: попробую, спасибо

Comment: И то что вы делаете уже реализовано в виде библиотеки: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding

Comment: посмотрю, спасибо. Ваш совет помог на сто процентов, мне это и надо было - сослаться на null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы сбросить слушатель нажатий надо в метод установки оного передать `null`

> button.setOnClickListener(null)

---

Также есть уже библиотека, в которой всё это (и многое другое) реализовано: [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding)

В её исходниках аналогичный код выглядит [так](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding3/view/ViewClickObservable.kt):

```
@CheckResult
fun View.clicks(): Observable<Unit> {
  return ViewClickObservable(this)
}

private class ViewClickObservable(
  private val view: View
) : Observable<Unit>() {

  override fun subscribeActual(observer: Observer<in Unit>) {
    if (!checkMainThread(observer)) {
      return
    }
    val listener = Listener(view, observer)
    observer.onSubscribe(listener)
    view.setOnClickListener(listener)
  }

  private class Listener(
    private val view: View,
    private val observer: Observer<in Unit>
  ) : MainThreadDisposable(), OnClickListener {

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
      if (!isDisposed) {
        observer.onNext(Unit)
      }
    }

    override fun onDispose() {
      view.setOnClickListener(null)
    }
  }
}
```